# Que signifie « chelou » ? Peut-on le traduire ?

Tags: sens, argot, verlan

J'ai lu ce mot dans les paroles d'une chanson et je ne trouve de traduction nulle part.

Que signifie-t-il ? et peut-on imaginer une traduction dans d'autres langues (anglais ou espagnol, par exemple) ?

Comment: Depends on the context, but one possible translation would be "weird".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ce mot est de l'argot [verlan](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan).

Il vient du mot **louche**, dans le sens de *homme louche*, dont on inverse les syllabes pour obtenir.... *chelou*. Sa "définition" se trouve [sur le wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chelou).

Le verlan est très populaire en France.

Vous pourrez trouver [quelques éléments de verlan sur **French Language** avec une recherche](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=verlan), mais, bizarrement, uniquement dans les réponses : aucun tag, et aucune question. Cet argot semble complètement inconnu de nos amis étrangers, alors qu'il est de pratique courante en France.

Comment cela se traduit-il ? Comme tous les argots :-)

Comment: +1 pour rappeler l'idée de recherche

Comment: Il faut préciser que verlan  = l'envers en verlan ! comme cet argot se construit, on peut soi-même en construire de nouveaux: ils sont "veaunou". Très usité dans les années 70, il est réapparu dans les années 90 (chelou date des années 90).

Comment: On peut ajouter qu'il existe du verlan de verlan, qui s'appelle la *reverlanisation*. *Femme* a donné *meuf* en verlan, qui a donné *feumeu* en verlan.

Answer (score 6):

The closest translation in English would be *sketchy* or *dodgy*. It means suspicious with a hint of contempt towards the person being described.

Answer (score 1):

Le mot chelou vient du mot *louche* en verlan.  On peut remplacer ce mot par *étrange*.

Comment: La [même réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/6173/358), et en beaucoup plus complet, a déjà été donnée. Il est inutile de faire une nouvelle réponse si on n'a aucun élément nouveau à apporter.